# When I create a new table referencing another table the Id it acquires is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

In my rails application I have an 3 tables. Venues, Events, and Bands.
I have my relationships set up but when I create a new event referencing the Venue it looks for another venue that does not exist in my show.erb file

These are my models

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
  has_many :bands, through: :events
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :band 
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
end
```

and my migration for events

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :date
      t.boolean :alcohol_served
      t.string :image
      t.belongs_to :venue, show:true
      t.belongs_to :band, show:true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my events controller for show I have

```
def show 
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  venue_id = Event.select(:venue_id).find(params[:id])
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
end
```

In this case I am able to see my events show page and it specifies the venue. I have 3 venues, 3 events, and 3 bands. The main issue is when I create a 4th event it looks for a 4th venue instead of the venue I specify.

Answer (score 2):

As Pavan pointed out, the base of your problem is that you are looking up the Venue by `params[:id]` in the `EventsController`, and within that controller `params[:id]` should refer to the `@event.id`.

Additionally, you show that you are looking up

```
venue_id = Event.select(:venue_id).find(params[:id])
```

which will give you the Venue id you are looking for and you can use this to do `@venue = Venue.find(venue_id)`, but there is a much more idiomatic Rails way to do this: `@venue = @event.venue`

You gain the `venue` method on events due to your `Venue` association `belongs_to :event`.  This is the same principle as using `@event.venues` because `Event` `has_many :venues`.

Rails ActiveRecord then knows how to find the Event and will generate some SQL which you can view in the console like `SELECT venues.* FROM venues WHERE venues.event_id = $1` and the placeholder `$1` gets replaced by the actual `@venue.event_id`.

Comment: so would you recommend that I put references in my venues and bands migrations? IE:  t.has_many :bands & t.has_many:events. So far I only have those type of references in my Events migrations

Comment: You currently have enough setup to do things like `@event.venue`, `@event.band`, `@venue.events`,`@venue.bands`,and `@band.events`.  If you were to add `Band.has_many :venues, through: :events` you could also do `@band.venues`.  I can't answer your comment any better because I don't know what you're seeking to do next.  If there is more you want to add to your original question then please edit and add to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I create a new event referencing the Venue it looks for another venue
>   that does not exist in my show.erb file

The problem is with how you fetch the `venues`, In your `events#show` method

```
@venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
```

should be

```
@venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
```

If `params[:venue_id]` isn't available, then you can simple do

```
@venue = @event.venue
```

Comment: I had tried that before, I thought it might have been in the right direction but it returns "Couldn't find Venue with 'id'=" error

Comment: @dutchkillsg That means params[:venue_id] is `nil`. Try `@venue = @event.venue`

Comment: that did it! thank you I appreciate it I was stuck on this for a while. Fairly new to rails so this was a practice applicatoin